# Optimal way to Subtract rows based on column values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to subtract the values of the rows based on the values of a different column. My dataframe looks like this:

```
Id |    col1    |  col2    | col3 |
1  | 2016-01-02 |  7:00:00 |  Yes |
1  | 2016-01-02 |  7:05:00 |  No  |
1  | 2016-01-02 |  7:10:00 |  Yes |
1  | 2016-01-02 |  8:00:00 |  No  |
2  | 2016-01-02 |  7:10:00 |  Yes | 
2  | 2016-01-02 |  7:50:00 |  No  | 
2  | 2016-01-02 |  9:00:00 |  No  | 
2  | 2016-01-02 |  9:10:00 |  No  | 
2  | 2016-01-02 |  9:15:00 |  No  | 
3  | 2016-01-02 |  6:05:00 |  Yes | 
3  | 2016-01-02 |  6:10:00 |  Yes | 
3  | 2016-01-02 |  6:20:00 |  Yes | 
3  | 2016-01-02 |  6:45:00 |  No  |
```

I need to calculate the average time difference in the combination of `col1` and `col2` based on the value of `col3`. The rule is the following:

> Whenever there is a `Yes` in `col3` do `row-next row`

A simplified version of what I have done so far is to loop through all the values in the dataframe and do this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['col3'][i] == 'Yes':
        date1 = datetime.combine(df['col1'][i], df['col2'][i])
        date2 = datetime.combine(df['col1'][i+1], df['col2'][i+1])
        dict[df['Id'][i]] = date1-date2
```

The variable `dict` is just a dictionary that holds the results for each different `Id`.

Since I have more than 6MM rows, the loop takes a lot of time to complete, so I was wondering if someone could come up with a more efficient and elegant solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
#datetime column - add time to dates
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['col2'])
#get difference of all values, filter by multiple mask only if `Yes`
#convert to ns for numeric for aggregate
df['dif']=df['datetime'].diff(-1).mul(df['col3'] == 'Yes').fillna(0).values.astype(np.int64)
print (df)
    Id        col1     col2 col3            datetime            dif
0    1  2016-01-02  7:00:00  Yes 2016-01-02 07:00:00  -300000000000
1    1  2016-01-02  7:05:00   No 2016-01-02 07:05:00              0
2    1  2016-01-02  7:10:00  Yes 2016-01-02 07:10:00 -3000000000000
3    1  2016-01-02  8:00:00   No 2016-01-02 08:00:00              0
4    2  2016-01-02  7:10:00  Yes 2016-01-02 07:10:00 -2400000000000
5    2  2016-01-02  7:50:00   No 2016-01-02 07:50:00              0
6    2  2016-01-02  9:00:00   No 2016-01-02 09:00:00              0
7    2  2016-01-02  9:10:00   No 2016-01-02 09:10:00              0
8    2  2016-01-02  9:15:00   No 2016-01-02 09:15:00              0
9    3  2016-01-02  6:05:00  Yes 2016-01-02 06:05:00  -300000000000
10   3  2016-01-02  6:10:00  Yes 2016-01-02 06:10:00  -600000000000
11   3  2016-01-02  6:20:00  Yes 2016-01-02 06:20:00 -1500000000000
12   3  2016-01-02  6:45:00   No 2016-01-02 06:45:00              0

d = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('Id')['dif'].mean()).to_dict()
print (d)
{1: Timedelta('-1 days +23:46:15'), 
 2: Timedelta('-1 days +23:52:00'), 
 3: Timedelta('-1 days +23:50:00')}
```

What is same as:

```
datetime = pd.to_datetime(df['col1']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['col2'])
diff = datetime.diff(-1).mul(df['col3'] == 'Yes').fillna(0).values.astype(np.int64)
d = pd.to_timedelta(pd.Series(diff, index=df.index).groupby(df['Id']).mean()).to_dict()
print (d)
{1: Timedelta('-1 days +23:46:15'), 
 2: Timedelta('-1 days +23:52:00'), 
 3: Timedelta('-1 days +23:50:00')}
```

But if need absolute values for remove negative timedelta add `numpy.abs`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['col2'])
df['dif'] = np.abs(df['datetime'].diff(-1)
                                 .mul(df['col3'] == 'Yes')
                                 .fillna(0)
                                 .values
                                 .astype(np.int64))
print (df)
    Id        col1     col2 col3            datetime            dif
0    1  2016-01-02  7:00:00  Yes 2016-01-02 07:00:00   300000000000
1    1  2016-01-02  7:05:00   No 2016-01-02 07:05:00              0
2    1  2016-01-02  7:10:00  Yes 2016-01-02 07:10:00  3000000000000
3    1  2016-01-02  8:00:00   No 2016-01-02 08:00:00              0
4    2  2016-01-02  7:10:00  Yes 2016-01-02 07:10:00  2400000000000
5    2  2016-01-02  7:50:00   No 2016-01-02 07:50:00              0
6    2  2016-01-02  9:00:00   No 2016-01-02 09:00:00              0
7    2  2016-01-02  9:10:00   No 2016-01-02 09:10:00              0
8    2  2016-01-02  9:15:00   No 2016-01-02 09:15:00              0
9    3  2016-01-02  6:05:00  Yes 2016-01-02 06:05:00   300000000000
10   3  2016-01-02  6:10:00  Yes 2016-01-02 06:10:00   600000000000
11   3  2016-01-02  6:20:00  Yes 2016-01-02 06:20:00  1500000000000
12   3  2016-01-02  6:45:00   No 2016-01-02 06:45:00              0

d = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('Id')['dif'].mean()).to_dict()
print (d)
{1: Timedelta('0 days 00:13:45'), 
 2: Timedelta('0 days 00:08:00'), 
 3: Timedelta('0 days 00:10:00')}
```

Comment: Yes, much more clean and fast. Can you please explain the mul function? I am looking at the documentation but I can't seem to understand what it is doing.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html

Comment: You can check [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html), it simply multiple to 1 if `Yes` and to `0` if not `Yes`.